# goClipse: internal error executing preparing launch. reason: java.lang.NullPointerException why?

Tags: eclipse, go, goclipse

I'm trying to install goClipse on ubuntu 14.04.
I've installed java8 from repository and i downloaded eclipse mars 4.5.

i tried this example code,in a file called hello.go:

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
fmt.Printf("hello, world\n")
}
```

but it work only from terminal with follow commands:

```
go run hello.go
```

thankyou

Comment: I personally don't use Goclipse. there are far better alternatives IMO. I know that's not what you asked, but try the IntelliJ plugin, LiteIDE, Atom or Sublime.

Comment: I agree with @Not_a_Golfer that ecplise isn't a very good IDE, especially for Go. But if you want to use it I suggest doing some searching for Eclipse errors because your problem has nothing to do with Go and everything to do with Ecplise being a piece of shit that can't even install itself without troubleshooting of dependencies. Generally the problems are due to your Java install but in this case, it may not know your Go path or something along those lines.

Comment: ecplise is bad, now.

Comment: Have you read the Goclipse UserGuide ( https://github.com/GoClipse/goclipse/blob/latest/documentation/UserGuide.md#user-guide ) to make sure you know how to configure and use Goclipse? What settings did you use for the Go compiler paths and arch? What is the output in the Go build console in Eclipse when you try to build the project?

Comment: i need to program a cuda-device with go language so i thought to use eclipse because i already use it for cuda.
Can you offer me an alternative?
I read Userguide and i set GOPATH and GOROOT. 
I wrote this on terminal:
    
              mkdir $HOME/go
              export GOPATH=$HOME/go
              export PATH=$PATH:GOPATH/bin

Comment: i just SOLVED!!!!
GOPATH subfolders are: "bin" , "pkg" and "src".
I created a folder into "src" and i paste source file "hello.go" in this new folder!
Now it work!!

Answer (score -1):

The "main.go" needs to be inside a sub directory inside the src folder of the project structure. Go files directly under the src folder are ignored. I suggest creating a "MainProgram" directory under src and running it from there.